# Is there any way to automatically compose/design an image/document containing text and images with varying size and length?

Tags: html, css, automation, transformation, data-representation

I need to automatically arrange a title, summary, description, file list, and images onto a printed page with a fixed size of 4.7"x4.7" (118x118 mm). The description and file list can vary in length. Some items may have a single file while another may have more than the page can fit. Some items may have a description that is a single sentence while another may have a wall of text. Some may have a single image while another many. What I need is to be able to use the space available effectively without creating a messy or cluttered page. The program should be able to vary the font size and image widths.

I have tried using iText7 HTML/CSS to PDF converter for C#. This specific renderer disregards certain CSS styling and will not use Javascript if needed. I will not provide an example of the PDF output because it is quite obvious that static rendering is not what I need.

Potentially a Chromium instance that is used to render a page created with HTML/CSS/JS would be desired, however this seems like the wrong tool for the job.

Here I have transformed this page into what I need manually.

https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/sakura
->
[Sakura Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi72j.jpg)

I have the data in the above example already in the form of json on my computer. There are 19136 others just like the example that need to be put onto its own page.

Comment: Have you heard of [`wkhtmltopdf`](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/)? As far as I know, it's a wrapper around WebKit's print-to-PDF feature. The project also includes a `wkhtmltoimage` command, which may save you a step.